# Change accepting states using automata and overlay-beamer-styles without having nodes shift around

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, overlays, automata

I am trying to draw an automaton using TikZ with the automata package that I am modifying from slide to slide with overlay-beamer-styles. One of the things I am changing is which nodes are marked as accepting states. However, changing this causes everything to shift around slightly, which looks bad when changing from slide to slide. How can I fix this? I would like all of the edges, node labels, etc to stay at the same places and only have the border of the nodes change, ideally by adding/removing the inner line.

Here is a minimum working example:

```tex
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{
    automata,
    overlay-beamer-styles}
    
\tikzset{
    accepting on/.style={alt=#1{accepting}{}}
}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[initial text=,auto,state/.append style={minimum size=1.5cm}]
        \node[state,initial,accepting on=<2>] (z0) at (0,0) {$z_0$};
        \node[state,accepting on=<1>] (z1) at (2,0) {$z_1$};
        
        \path[->] (z0) edge [loop above] node {$a$} (z0)
                       edge node {$b$} (z1)
                  (z1) edge [loop above] node {$a,b$} (z1);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

and here is the output:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se and thanks for adding a minimal document. Related questions: [How can I fix jumping TikZ pictures in beamer?](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/18704), [Strange movement of objects when highlighted item in beamer is uncovered](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/85205).

Comment: The problem here is that the `accepting` is done by `double` which changes the size of the node (which also changes the path of the loobs very slightly resulting in a different placement of the node along the loop).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The automata style `accepting by double` is defined as

```
\tikzset{accepting by double/.style= {double,outer sep=.5\pgflinewidth+.3pt}} % .3pt is half double width distance
```

This means that not only a double line is added, but also that the size of the node changes due to the different `outer sep`.

You can avoid the node from jumping between overlays, if you increase the `outer sep` also on the non-accepted overlays:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{
    automata,
    overlay-beamer-styles}
    
\tikzset{
    accepting on/.style={alt=#1{accepting}{accepting, double=none}}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[initial text=,auto,state/.append style={minimum size=1.5cm}]
        \node[state,initial,accepting on=<2>] (z0) at (0,0) {$z_0$};
        \node[state,accepting on=<1>] (z1) at (2,0) {$z_1$};
        
        \path[->] (z0) edge [loop above] node {$a$} (z0)
                       edge node {$b$} (z1)
                  (z1) edge [loop above] node {$a,b$} (z1);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Might be more robust to do `accepting on/.style={alt=#1{accepting}{accepting, double=none}}`.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Do you have a specific scenario in mind where this is necessary? From the top of my head, I can only think of a case where the users explicitly uses the double for the node, but if they do this, I think the state should actually be doubled?

Comment: If someone changes the `accepting`/`accepting by double` style. Unlikely but I just don't like hard-coded numbers.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Ah, makes sense! Thanks!

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly. As a sidenote, do you know where I could find the source code for the Tikz libraries online? I was trying to look up the definition of `accepting` myself, but I couldn't find the source code online, and I don't have a local TeX install on my PC because I tend to use Overleaf or my uni's ShareLaTeX instance.

Comment: @Kalobi You can find the code at https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/blob/master/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibraryautomata.code.tex#L35

Answer (score 3):

The `double`ing changes the node size which lead to the typical problem of the whole TikZ picture being a bit wider and higher (first instance of jumping) but in this case it will also change the loops and the nodes placed a long the loop a bit (second instance of jumping).

While [samcarter's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/688876) compensates this by making the non-accepting state as big as the accepting one (which will lead to a bit whitespace between the node's border and the arrow) this answer tries to solve this by making the accepting one as big as the non-accepting one:

1. By not `double`ing the path but by offsetting it via the `nfold` library.

   For circles this works perfectly. For other shapes, this might not work as neatly. The `rectangle` shape isn't handled correctly by `nfold` ([yet?](https://github.com/jonschz/tikz-nfold/issues/15)) and the offset needs to be inverted since the rectangle is constructed in the other direction.

   But we could add a boolean to flip/flop the offset easily.
2. By adding another circle node that's only drawn and has no text.

   This is actually my preferred version if your states all had the same size and shape otherwise you would need to adapt this a bit depending on how your states vary. (Though, we could easily add a nice interface to do this.)

   In its current form it's very inflexible and uses hard-coded numbers. (We could measure the original node and make the label's size dependent on that.)

   Though, when you start using colors, transformation or other fancy stuff this might break very easily.
3. By the original `double`ing via `accepting by double` but by making the node a bit smaller.

   This only works if the node is big enough, i.e. the `minimum width`/`height` is not exceeded because the text is too big.

Overall I'd prefer the solution via `nfold`, especially if you only use circles since it has the least interference in case you customize your `state`s.

### Code

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,overlay-beamer-styles,nfold}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{offset/.code=\tikz@addmode{\pgfgetpath\tikz@temp\pgfsetpath\pgfutil@empty\pgfoffsetpath\tikz@temp{#1}}}
\makeatother
\tikzset{
  accepting by offset/.style={postaction={path only, draw, offset=#1}},
  accepting by label/.style={label={[circle,path only, draw, minimum size={1.5cm-(#1)}]center:}},
  accepting by smaller/.style={
    accepting by double,
    minimum width/.expanded={\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/minimum width}-(\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer xsep})-.5\pgflinewidth},
    minimum height/.expanded={\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/minimum height}-(\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer ysep})-.5\pgflinewidth}},
  set accepting on/offset/.style={accepting on/.style={alt={##1{accepting by offset={#1}}{}}}},
  set accepting on/label/.style={accepting on/.style={alt={##1{accepting by label={#1}}{}}}},
  set accepting on/smaller/.style={accepting on/.style={alt={##1{accepting by smaller}{}}}},
  set accepting on/offset=+1pt, % just a default
}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Accepting by offset}
\begin{tikzpicture}[initial text=, auto, state/.append style={minimum size=1.5cm}]
  \node[state,initial,accepting on=<2>] (z0) at (0,0) {$z_0$};
  \node[state,accepting on=<1>] (z1) at (2,0) {$z_1$};
  \path[->] (z0) edge [loop above] node {$a$} (z0)
                 edge node {$b$} (z1)
            (z1) edge [loop above] node {$a,b$} (z1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Accepting by label}
\tikzset{set accepting on/label=2pt}
\begin{tikzpicture}[initial text=, auto, state/.append style={minimum size=1.5cm}]
  \node[state,initial,accepting on=<2>] (z0) at (0,0) {$z_0$};
  \node[state,accepting on=<1>] (z1) at (2,0) {$z_1$};
  \path[->] (z0) edge [loop above] node {$a$} (z0)
                 edge node {$b$} (z1)
            (z1) edge [loop above] node {$a,b$} (z1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Accepting by smaller}
\tikzset{set accepting on/smaller=.3pt+\pgflinewidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}[initial text=, auto, state/.append style={minimum size=1.5cm}]
  \node[state,initial,accepting on=<2>] (z0) at (0,0) {$z_0$};
  \node[state,accepting on=<1>] (z1) at (2,0) {$z_1$};
  \path[->] (z0) edge [loop above] node {$a$} (z0)
                 edge node {$b$} (z1)
            (z1) edge [loop above] node {$a,b$} (z1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Very nice solution!